# Get the consecutive months for a given date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my table I have dates as follows

```
08/08/2011
29/08/2011
30/08/2011
31/08/2011
12/09/2011
13/09/2011
23/10/2011
24/10/2011
25/10/2011
26/10/2011
```

Now I need the records to be displayed based on a given **date range** eg: if from date is `8/08/2011` and to date is `20/10/2011` then the data should come as below

```
29/08/2011   Aug
30/08/2011   Aug
31/08/2011   Aug
12/09/2011   Sept
13/09/2011   Sept
```

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: Also, I don't understand 'consecutive' in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAsed on the data you provided

```
CREATE TABLE notes
(`datecreated` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO notes
  (`datecreated`)
VALUES
  ('08/08/2011'),
  ('29/08/2011'),
  ('30/08/2011'),
  ('31/08/2011'),
  ('12/09/2011'),
  ('13/09/2011'),
  ('23/10/2011'),
  ('24/10/2011'),
  ('25/10/2011'),
  ('26/10/2011')
  ;
```

You can use

```
 Select 
   STR_TO_DATE(datecreated, '%d/%c/%Y') datecreated 
   , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datecreated, '%d/%c/%Y'),'%b') monthname
 From notes
 WHERE 
   STR_TO_DATE(datecreated, '%d/%c/%Y') BETWEEN '2011-08-29' AND '2011-09-13';
```

the result is

```
datecreated     monthname
2011-08-29      Aug
2011-08-30      Aug
2011-08-31      Aug
2011-09-12      Sep
2011-09-13      Sep
```

The biggest Problem is that your date is not in a Format that mysql can import.
 But with STR_TO_DATE you can solve this.
the date Problems as you can see keeps bugging mysql.
The WHERE clause uses BETWEEN to select the wanted date frame this has to be in the right date format. Of course you have to adept it to your tablebane and columnname

[DBfiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=da75b0fff6296c2be5247c6a280e8b3b)

Comment: It's just a terrible idea. Don't even entertain it. Just fix the dates.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the data so it uses `date`, the proper format for storing a date:

```
update notes
    set datecreated = str_to_date(datecreated, '%d/%m/%Y');

alter table notes modify column datecreated date;

select *
from notes;
```

Then, if you want to sort the data, just use:

```
order by datecreated;
```

If you want your exact result set:

```
select datecreated, left(monthname(datecreated), 3)
from notes
where datecreated < '2011-10-01'
order by datecreated;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0043fba0e6b1659f62efdce1cef805a5) is a db<>fiddle.